# swift: convert long/int64 to date

Tags: swift

I want to convert 1529704800000 to a Date object but I don't get the right date. I'm getting the value out of a json. I'm converting the value on this way:

```
class Example: Decodable {

    var id: Int64?
    var date: Date?

    init(json: [String: Any]) {
        id = json["id"] as? Int64 ?? -1
        var dateTime = (json["date"] as AnyObject? as? Int64) ?? 0
        date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: (TimeInterval(dateTime / 1000)))
    }

     static func fetchReportsForUser(authorId: Int64) -> [Report]? {
        let urlString = "http://localhost:8080/test-application/rest/example/"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        var examples = [Example]()
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else {
                    return
                }
                if(data.isEmpty) {
                    group.leave()
                    return
                }
                do {
                    examples = try JSONDecoder().decode([Example].self, from: data)
                } catch let err {
                    print(err)
                }
                group.leave()
            }.resume()
        }
        group.wait()
        return examples
    }
}
```

When I do it like that I still get 50472-09-04 16:00:00 +0000 as date. I tried it with Double instead of Int64 but I got the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just let `JSONDecoder` do the job by using the appropriate *date decoding strategy*

```
let json = """
{"id" : 1, "date" : 1529704800000}
"""

struct Example : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let date : Date
}

let data = Data(json.utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970
do {
    let result = try decoder.decode(Example.self, from: data)
    print(result) // Example(id: 1, date: 2018-06-22 22:00:00 +0000)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Note: Don't make an asynchronous task synchronous. Learn to understand asynchronous data processing and use a completion handler.

Comment: thank you for the solution and for the advice. Now It works :)

Comment: Great solution - I've learned about `dateDecodingStrategy` now!

Comment: There are two more advices: `dataTask` uses its own background thread. The explicit `DispatchQueue` is redundant. And don't use weird syntax like `json["date"] as AnyObject? as? Int64`, a `[String:Any]` dictionary can be downcasted to `Int64` directly: `json["date"] as? Int64`

Answer (score 2):

Your integer seems to represent milliseconds rather than seconds, this it is giving a date thousands of years in the future!

Dividing it by 1000 (removing the last 3 zeros) gives 22 June 2018 10pm UTC.

Also, try changing the lines where you cast from the `json` to a date:

```
if let dateTime = json["date"] as? Int {
    date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: dateTime/1000)
}
```

Comment: I'm already dividing it by 1000 and I get the wrong date. Do you mean I have to divide it a second time by 1000?

Comment: @Yupp I have edited the answer. You might need to change the part where you cast the json to a date. Currently, a Unix timestamp measured in seconds should have 10 digits. Your initial number has 13, so only need to divide by 1000 once.